# Ruby gem or other

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am creating a ruby on rails app, and am looking for something to allow my users to draw on a picture, then save the result, whether it's a ruby gem, a JS/jquery plugin, or CSS. I am looking for something that is documented and maintained. Not sure if the gem Paperclip can handle this or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Jquery plugin](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/) to take input coordinates from user.

Or you can pass these coordinates to either of the gems below to draw shapes/lines.

These gems should help you get started.

[Rmagick](http://rubyinrails.com/2014/04/15/ruby-draw-line-image-using-rmagick/) & a [tutorial](https://rmagick.github.io/rvgtut.html)
[ChunkyPNG](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png/wiki/Drawing)